# No sound i browser and sm player

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio

Hello im running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it have worked fine.

But suddently the sound stopped working in all my browsers and the videoplayer SM player.

Sound works in VLC player, and then i choose and test speakers in settings they works too.

Someone knows what the problem can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How i solved it:

In `~/.config/pulse`, there happened to be multiple config files. I just moved them to a new folder within the directory, and did run killall pulse

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

and then reboot.

It is working now.

Comment: What worked for me was to just delete the ~/.config/pulse folder and reboot.